# Existe algum site ou PDF com exercícios para manipulação de arrays?

Tags: php, array

Queria saber se vocês conhecem algum site ou têm PDFs ou qualquer outra coisa que tenha exercícios com funções para manipulação de arrays em PHP.

Recorri ao SOpt, pois vasculhei bastante na internet e não obtive resultados.

Se tiverem, por gentileza, me passem; estou necessitando para uma prova.

Comment: O manual oficial é muito bom! http://php.net só tem algumas coisas má traduzidas que é legal dar um Google mesmo.

Comment: Mas o manual apenas ensina como usar, não oferece exercício. That's the problem :/

Comment: Faça esses http://professor.leonardomeirelles.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Lista-de-Exerc%C3%ADcios-Array1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Array eu achava que era um bicho de sete cabeças, mas são só simples variáveis poderosas.

Uma variável normal pode guardar meu nome, por exemplo:

```
$nome = "Lucas";
```

Se dermos um `echo` o que vai ser exibido é:

```
Lucas
```

Ja com array, é isso que eu disse, são "variáveis" só que guardam mais informações.

Por exemplo, pode guardar meu nome e sobrenome:

```
$nomeSobrenome = ["Lucas"];
$nomeSobrenome = ["Carvalho"];
```

Do jeito que escrevi acima, ela criou 2 espaços , ou seja, começando contar do 0, ela criou o 0 e o 1. Mesma coisa se eu tivesse criado duas variáveis diferentes. Se eu der um `echo $nomeSobrenome[0] . " " . $nomeSobrenome[1]`, o ponto no meio ali, serve para concatenar, ou seja, pra acrescentar/integrar duas informações num mesmo comando, sem precisar ficar dando um monte de echo, e o espaço que dei ali, com as aspas, é pra dar espaço entre os comandos. Vai exibir assim no final:

```
Lucas Carvalho
```

Em vez de números inteiros nos indices das arrays, pode também consultar elas por strings:

```
$pessoa = ["nome" => "Lucas de Carvalho Alves"];
```

Se eu der um echo `$pessoa['nome'];`

Vai exibir `Lucas de Carvalho Alves`
Isso porque "nome" recebeu "Lucas de Carvalho Alves" pelo sinal de `=>` (setinha) é meio que fosse um sinal somente de igual `=` , no caso, é um sinal de atribuição.

Não tem muito segredo, é somente criar os seus próprios exercícios, e ir praticando.